# Trying to create a button with 2 states

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to create a button with 2 states that it can be switched between by clicking on it. Something like the like button facebook has. It switches between the grey not-liked stage and the blue liked stage. I'm trying to do this with an icon I created.

**html (using 6 of them in my code)**

```
<img id="list" src="img/listwhite.svg">
```

**css**

```
section article div img {
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    opacity: 0.2; 
}

#list {
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

#listselected {
    transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

**javascript**

```
function listClick (){
    document.getElementById('list').id = 'listselected';
}
document.getElementById("list").addEventListener("click", listClick);


function listunClick (){
    document.getElementById('listselected').id = 'list';
}
document.getElementById("listselected").addEventListener("click", listunClick);
```

Right now using this code, the first part works, but during the second part something goes wrong. Instead of changing the state of this first icon, the state of another #list on my site will change to #listselected. I don't know what to change right now and I was hoping you guys could help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Did you actually forget the closing curly brackets, or did you just miss them during copy & paste?

Comment: @Timo He does close the curly brackets -- it's just a very unusual way of doing so :P

Comment: Oh, I see. Now that's a style I haven't seen before.

Comment: `the state of another #list on my site will change to #listselected` - You're not allowed to have duplicate IDs on one page if you want JavaScript to work.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow  and I had trouble getting my code in there.

Comment: Why not use a checkbox, and use CSS to change how it displays depending on whether it's checked or not? Checkboxes automatically switch between states whenever you click them.

Answer (score 1):

You need quite a few changes, but here's a basic working example.

They key is you dont want to change the ID of your element, rather apply and remove a class `.selected`

```css
#list {
  height: 3em;
  width: auto;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

#list {
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

#list.selected {
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<img id="list" onclick="this.classList.toggle('selected')" src="http://mygimptutorial.com/images/button-with-reflection/11.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is **toggle** between two declaration blocks. This can be easily done with the `toggle` method in the `classList` object. In order for this to be achieved, you must change the id selectors to class selectors.

```js
document.querySelector('.list').classList.toggle('insert-class-name');
```

Comment: Iv'e changed my Javascript into this and I inserted .listselected as class name. Also changed the id to a class and the # to a . but nothing is happening. Am I understanding you wrong?